# Javascript snake game apple respawn

Tags: javascript

I have made a snake game in JavaScript and it works great. The thing I want to implement into this game is that if the snake does not eat the apple in a 5 or 10 second interval, the apple re-spawns in another place. While it's obvious I should use `setInterval`, it doesn't work because I already have a set interval that calls the game function 15 times in a second. I cannot find a way to delay this function of moving the apple as desired. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code for the game:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canv = document.getElementById("gc");
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
  setInterval(game, 1000 / 15);
}
px = py = 10;
gs = tc = 20;
ax = ay = 15;
xv = yv = 0;
trail = [];
tail = 5;

function game() {
  px += xv;
  py += yv;
  if (px < 0) {
    px = tc - 1;
  }
  if (px > tc - 1) {
    px = 0;
  }
  if (py < 0) {
    py = tc - 1;
  }
  if (py > tc - 1) {
    py = 0;
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
    if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
      tail = 5;
    }
  }
  trail.push({
    x: px,
    y: py
  });
  while (trail.length > tail) {
    trail.shift();
  }

  if (ax == px && ay == py) {
    tail++;
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      xv = -1;
      yv = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      xv = 0;
      yv = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      xv = 1;
      yv = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      xv = 0;
      yv = 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: If you call your function 15 times a second, then just check every 60 calls if the apple has been eaten or not, and then reset the count.

Comment: As far as I know you can set as many intervals as you want in Javascript, and they will all run properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach (already mentioned in the comments) is to express your "maximum apple age" in terms of *frames* rather than *seconds*.

Since you already have a main game loop of 15 fps, you can use this frame rate to build your apple logic:

In the game state (in your case, the global scope):

```
var appleAge = 0;
var fps = 15;
var maxAppleAgeSeconds = 3;
var maxAppleAgeFrames = maxAppleAgeSeconds * fps;
```

In the `game` function:

```
if (/* hits apple */) {
  tail++;
  /* make new apple */
  appleAge = 0;
} else {
  appleAge++;

  if (appleAge > maxAppleAgeFrames) {
    /* make new apple */
    appleAge = 0;
  }
}
```

Some general advice:

- Declare your variables using `var` (or, if you're using more modern language features, `let` and `const`)
- Use more functions to make your code easier to read, understand and maintain. For example:

  ```
  // Hard to understand what this does...
  ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
  ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);

  // Easier to understand:
  function moveAppleToRandomLocation() {
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
  }

  // elsewhere:
  moveAppleToRandomLocation();
  ```

The changes in a snippet:

```js
// TODO: fix var. declarations
window.onload = function() {
  canv = document.getElementById("gc");
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
  setInterval(game, 1000 / 15);
}
px = py = 10;
gs = tc = 20;
ax = ay = 15;
xv = yv = 0;
trail = [];
tail = 5;

// New:
var fps = 15;
var maxAppleAgeSeconds = 5;
var appleAge = 0;
var maxAppleAgeFrames = fps * maxAppleAgeSeconds;


function game() {
  px += xv;
  py += yv;
  if (px < 0) {
    px = tc - 1;
  }
  if (px > tc - 1) {
    px = 0;
  }
  if (py < 0) {
    py = tc - 1;
  }
  if (py > tc - 1) {
    py = 0;
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
    if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
      tail = 5;
    }
  }
  trail.push({
    x: px,
    y: py
  });
  while (trail.length > tail) {
    trail.shift();
  }

  appleAge++;

  if (ax == px && ay == py) {
    tail++;
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    appleAge = 0;
  } else if (appleAge > maxAppleAgeFrames) {
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    appleAge = 0;
  }
  
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      xv = -1;
      yv = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      xv = 0;
      yv = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      xv = 1;
      yv = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      xv = 0;
      yv = 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: You did help me better understand what i'm looking for, but even when i implemented your code in this, it still doesn't work, after the 3 seconds, the apple just goes wild and spawns everywhere continuously, i really can't figure out why it does that.

Comment: Did you make sure to differentiate between *frames* and *seconds*. 3 frames -> apple moves 5 times per second. 3 * 15 = 45 frames -> apple moves every 3 seconds.

Comment: BTW: You can expand the snippet in my answer to see the working implementation

Comment: Yes. I checked everything and i wrote it just as you did, that's exactly why it confuses me, because it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: You'll have to step through your code to see what's going wrong. If you post your current code here I can try to help out.

Comment: I got it to work. Stupidest mistake i ever made, didn't upload to server, thought it automatically did already. Helped out a lot and solved my issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple intervals in javascript and will work fine, see below snippet for example..
So in your case you can put something like this:

```
let gameInterval = setInterval(game, 1000/15);
let appleInterval = setInterval(() => { /* your apple function goes here */}, 1000/5);
```

```js
let a = setInterval(() => {console.log("every 2 seconds")}, 2000);
let b = setInterval(() => {console.log("every 3 seconds")}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
Score<div id="score"></div>
Record<div id="record"></div>
<script>
window.onload=function () {
    var vel = 15;
    var velocity = 1000/15;
    canv=document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush);
    setInterval(game,1000/vel);
}

let px = 10;
let py =10;
let gs = 20;
let tc = 20;
let ax = ay = 15;
let xv=yv=0;
let trail=[];
let tail = 5;
let sc = 0;
let rec= 0;
var vel = 5;

var fps = 15;
var maxAppleAgeSeconds = 5;
var appleAge = 0;
var maxAppleAgeFrames = fps * maxAppleAgeSeconds;


function game() {
    px+=xv;
    py+=yv;
    if(px<0) {
        px= tc-1;
    }
    if(px>tc-1) {
        px= 0;
    }
    if(py<0) {
        py= tc-1;
    }
    if(py>tc-1) {
        py= 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);

    ctx.fillStyle="lime";
    for(var i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*gs,trail[i].y*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
        if(trail[i].x==px && trail[i].y==py) {
           tail = 5;
           px=py=10;
            gs=tc=20;
            ax=ay=15;
            xv=yv=0;
            trail=[];
            vel = 15;
            if (sc > rec) {
                rec = sc;
                record.innerText = rec;
            }
            sc = 0;

        }
    }
    trail.push({x:px,y:py});
    while(trail.length>tail) {
    trail.shift();
    }

  appleAge++;

  if (ax == px && ay == py) {
            tail+=3;
            sc++
            score.innerText = sc;
            vel += 50;
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    appleAge = 0;
  } else if (appleAge > maxAppleAgeFrames) {
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    appleAge = 0;
        }    
    ctx.fillStyle="orange";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*gs,ay*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
}
function keyPush(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            xv=-1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv=0;yv=-1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv=1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv=0;yv=1;
            break;
    }    
}
</script>
```